# cURL Cloudant attachment example please

Tags: cloudant

Please forgive me for the potentially basic question but I am a z/OS person trying to learn cURL and Cloudant.  I have gotten the following example to work to add a record to a database (using DOS from Windows) :

```
curl -X POST -b /tmp/cloudant.cookie -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"_id\":\"2\",\"empName\":\"John Doe\",\"phone\":\"646-598-4133\",\"age\":\"28\"}" --url https://xxxxxxxxxx-bluemix.cloudant.com/rcdb
```

Now I would like to add a _attachment image1.jpg dile to that record...

Could anyone please tell me what the syntax on windows would be...trying a few combinations but nothing so far works.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you have gotten this to work in DOS but have not gotten it to work in Windows. I'm not a Windows user, but my understanding is that a DOS terminal is run inside of Windows for this sort of thing (a "Command Prompt" window). I'm confused what the difference between DOS and a Windows Command Prompt is in the context of your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi Bradley..thanks for responding...Actually I meant that I have gotten the above command to work in a DOS command window in Windows 7...sorry for the confusion...My problem is the syntax of the command...lots of " and \ and { etc...  This is the command I am trying now what its not working correctly giving me the following error "{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}"...I know from trying over and over that the command is just not formatted correctly..likely misplaced or missing " or \...

Comment: curl -X POST -b /tmp/cloudant.cookie -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"_id\":\"3\",\"empName\":\"John Doe\",\"phone\":\"646-598-4133\",\"age\":\"28\",\"_attachments\":{\"image1.jpg\",{\"content_type\":\"image/jpeg\"}}}" --url https://xxxxxxxx-bluemix.cloudant.com/rcdb

Answer (score 2):

To add an attachment follow the instructions in the Cloudant documentation at https://docs.cloudant.com/attachments.html

Example:

Assuming you have already created a document with ID "2" and revision number "1-954695fb9642f02975d76b959d0b5e98" in database rcdb, run the following command:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" --data-binary "@image1.jpg" --url https://xxxxxxxxxx-bluemix.cloudant.com/$DATABASE/$DOCUMENT_ID/$ATTACHMENT?rev=$REV
```

replacing $DATABASE with rcdb, $DOCUMENT_ID with 2, $REV with 1-954695fb9642f02975d76b959d0b5e98 and $ATTACHMENT with the desired attachment property name, e.g. mypic.

Comment: (Add-on because I can't enter more than two links) The final URL should look as follows: https://xxxxxxxxxx-bluemix.cloudant.com/rcdb/2/mypic?rev=1-954695fb9642f02975d76b959d0b5e98

Comment: Thank you ptitzler that worked!...I am happy with that answer although I am curious how the JSON type command with the _attachments (not inline jpg but pointing to the image.1 file name) command would look like.  If you can show me how you would format that one that would be great..if not I am happy with the one you sent..thank you!!